# Nginx/Certbot - invalid response from domain/.well-known

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https, certificate, certbot

I'm trying to set up `https` on our web page which runs on `Django 1.8`. I'm very new in this area so I use [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-nginx). I followed the instructions until `./path/to/certbot-auto certonly`.

> ### How would you like to authenticate with the ACME CA?
>
> - 1: Place files in webroot directory (webroot)
> - 2: Spin up a temporary webserver (standalone)

I've chosen 1.

Then it wants my domain and the next step is:

> Select the webroot for salix.sk:

```
>>> /home/django/salix
```

which returns error

> Waiting for verification... Cleaning up challenges Failed
>   authorization procedure. salix.sk (http-01):
>   urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient
>   authorization :: Invalid response from
>   http://salix.sk/.well-known/acme-challenge/some_code:
>   "      
>   Page not"
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: salix.sk    Type:   unauthorized    Detail: Invalid
>   response from
>   http://salix.sk/.well-known/acme-challenge/some_code:
>   "            
>        
>        Page not"
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address.

I think that I should somehow set the path in my project but can't figure out how. It created a folder `.well-known` inside the root of my project without any visible files inside.

Do you know what to do?

**EDIT:**
I've changed `etc/nginx/sites-available/default` adding into server section:

```
location ~ /.well-known {
                    allow all;
            }
```

So:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
}
```

Which didn't help too.

Comment: You use /usr/share/nginx/html path as html nginx root. So you should specify the same path to Certbot. Something like ./path/to/certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /usr/share/nginx/html -d salix.sk

Answer (score 0):

In my case this configuration of nginx works well:

```
location ^~ /.well-known {
        if ($request_uri ~* /.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)) {
        set $tmp $1.ZzFvB6sHz7artk-kNCGMNtB_adt6f5K2tuL8Mf8uL1c;
    }
    return 200 $tmp;
```

Here I get the $1 - first element from the end of request_uri, add a string, generated by certbot during `certbot renew` command execution.

But I am not sure it would work the next time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete AAAA record for IPv6 address - fix for me

Answer (score 0):

can use root user run

in nginx.conf  set code

user  root root;

Comment: This is unclear, are you trying to answer? Is this another question? Please clarify

Answer (score -1):

Try:

1. apt update, apt upgrade
2. Change timezone and date/time to actual
3. Delete AAAA record for IPv6 address